# Getting wrong results using AND and OR conditionals in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+
| BackCheckId |                TaskId                |               EmpGuid                | CompletedDate |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+
|           1 | B92F7079-2011-44D6-B3C4-BD2F7481C97F | 6074CAEA-7A8E-4699-9451-16C2EAF394EF | NULL          |
|           2 | 82AB0C4B-9342-46FA-ACBE-C00B87571BF9 | 6074CAEA-7A8E-4699-9451-16C2EAF394EF | NULL          |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Query to create:

```
CREATE TABLE Backchecks(
  BackCheckId int,
  TaskId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  EmpGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  CompletedDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Backchecks VALUES
(1, 'B92F7079-2011-44D6-B3C4-BD2F7481C97F', '6074CAEA-7A8E-4699-9451-16C2EAF394EF',NULL),
(2, '82AB0C4B-9342-46FA-ACBE-C00B87571BF9','6074CAEA-7A8E-4699-9451-16C2EAF394EF',NULL)
```

That I want to do is to filter this data depending of `currentEmpGuid` so I declare variables to test it as:

```
 DECLARE @CurrentEmpGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'CC713AC9-ED79-47E3-BA37-47F2D5009BFC'   
DECLARE @FilterEmpKey INT = NULL
    SELECT * FROM Backchecks AS BC 
    WHERE [BC].[CompletedDate] IS NULL
                           AND (@FilterEmpKey IS NULL
                            OR [BC].[EmpGuid] = @CurrentEmpGuid)
```

So as you can see it should not return any result because `BC.EmpGuid` does not equals to any result in table, but for some reason I'm getting results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use () for the condition OR

Comment: I try but I get same result @TonyDong

Comment: Why are you INSERT records into People table? there is nothing wrong with the Select statement you posted here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> BC.EmpGuid does not equals to any result in table, but for some reason I'm getting results. What am I doing wrong?

```
 WHERE [BC].[CompletedDate] IS NULL
```

This is TRUE for both rows and

```
(@FilterEmpKey IS NULL
      OR [BC].[EmpGuid] = @CurrentEmpGuid)
```

is also TRUE for all rows since @FilterEmpKey is NULL.  The `[BC].[EmpGuid] = @CurrentEmpGuid` only has to be evaluated if you set @FilterEmpKey to some non-null value.